# Join dataframe with order by desc limit on spark /java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm using the following code :

```
Dataset <Row> dataframee =  df1.as("a").join(df2.as("b"),
            df2.col("id_device").equalTo(df1.col("ID_device_previous")).
                    and(df2.col("id_vehicule").equalTo(df1.col("ID_vehicule_previous"))).
                and(df2.col("tracking_time").lt(df1.col("date_track_previous")))
            ,"left").selectExpr("a.*", "b.ID_tracking as ID_pprevious", "b.km as KM_pprevious","b.tracking_time as tracking_time_pprevious","b.speed as speed_pprevious");
```

I get the df1 dataframe join with multiple line from df2 dataframe.

But what I want is to join the `df1` dataframe with `df2` dataframe ON the same condition and order by `df2.col("tracking_time") desc limit(0,1)`

**EDIT**

I tried the following code , but it doesn't work .

```
df1.registerTempTable("data");
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("tdays");
Dataset<Row> d_f = sparkSession.sql("select a.*  from data as a  LEFT JOIN (select  b.tracking_time from tdays as b where  b.id_device = a.ID_device_previous and  b.id_vehicule = a.ID_vehicule_previous  and b.tracking_time < a.date_track_previous order by b.tracking_time desc limit 1 )");
```

I need your help

Comment: you can use spark-sql and create tempViews on dataframes and join then using SQL query. (or) you can do dropDuplicates("columms") after join ... but make sure to increase shuffle partition count when doing dropDuplicates if you have huge input data.

Comment: can you give me an example ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in multiple ways which I'm aware of

1. you can do dropDuplicates on your joined **dataframee** DF.

   val finalDF = dataframee.dropDuplicates("") // specified columns which you want to be distinct/unique in final output

(OR)

2. spark-sql

   ```
   import spark.sql.implicits._
   df1.createOrReplaceTempViews("table1")
   df2.createOrReplaceTempViews("table2")
   spark.sql("join query with groupBy distinct columns").select(df("*"))
   ```

Comment: check order by and then group by (specify columns which you want to be distinct in op in group by).

Comment: I didn't understand